How to install nvidia driver/control panel Geforce 8400 GS
i look so many tutorials and answer and nothing seems to work, i always mess it up and have to re-install the whole OS, please any help?

Your GPU is quite old. The first version was released in 2007.
See this Wikipedia link about the 8300 and 8400 series.
As NVidia discontinued the driver for many newer GPUs, the only option remaining is using the nouveau driver. This is one question that attempts to explain how to do this.
